# hide table heading if all values in table are null

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a model form that I am displaying in a table. The form has about 40 fields broken down into 6 different tables. I have setup an if statements to not display the table elements if the field is empty in the db. This works as expected the only issue is that if all the elements are hidden the table header is still displayed. How could I hide the table header if all if the elements in that particular table are hidden.

```
<table class="post-table">
    <tr>
        <th class="table-header" colspan="2">
            <h3>Pool Details</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        {% if post.pool_size != '' %}
        <tr>
            <td>pool size:</td>
            <td>{{ post.pool_size }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %} 
        {% if post.pool_style != '' %}
        <tr>
            <td>Pool Style:</td>
            <td>{{ post.pool_style }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update:

```
        <table class="post-table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-header" COLSPAN="1" id="tab_header">
                <H3>ADDITIONAL INFO</H3>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tab_body">
            {% if post.additional_info != '' %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ post.additional_info }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>

    <script>
        let tbody = document.getElementById("tab_body").innerHTML;
        if (tbody === '') {
            tab_header = document.getElementById("tab_header").innerHTML = " ";
        } else {
            // Nothing to do i guess
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <table class="post-table" id="table-example">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-header" COLSPAN="1" id="tab_header">
                <H3>ADDITIONAL INFO</H3>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tab_body">
            {% if post.additional_info != '' %}
                <tr>
                    <td id="test">{{ post.additional_info }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    
    <script>
        var tbl = document.getElementById('table-example');
        if (tbl.rows.length == 1) {
            console.log('IT WORKED')
            tab_header = document.getElementById("tab_header").innerHTML = "";
            
        }
        console.log(tbl.rows.length)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to hide the header if the `<tbody>` is empty :
Suppose that we have `<th id="tab_header">Tab header</th>` `<tbody id="tab_body">Some content here</tbody>`
Then

```
let tbody = document.getElementById("tab_body").innerHTML;
# Check if it contains something
if (tbody === '') {
    tab_header = document.getElementById("tab_header").innerHTML = "";
} else {
    // Nothing to do i guess
}
```

**NB** Be aware about checking the content of  may be it is not empty string but sme other thing else.

Comment: Could you take a look at my update, I believe I have it implemented correctly but it is not hiding the table header.

Comment: Can you log var tbody in the console : `console.log(tbody)`

Comment: Try : `console.log(tbody ==='')` to check if tbody is empty string

Comment: returns `false` perhaps I should use null instead?

Comment: Ok it means that tbody is not empty string.  let me 5 min to check

Comment: still false with null

Comment: Even if I remove all of the code from the table body it still returns false

Comment: Wait i'm try to reproduce the same thing. But try `tbody` == '' **not 3 equals but 2**

Comment: Try this one : `if (tbody.length == 0) { ... }` it work

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, going to do some more testing

Comment: got it to work! only issue is it only removes the header text and leaves the css styling going to keep working!

Comment: Try to put the `id="tab_header"` on the `<tr>` level. With this, you will also remove the node on witch the `css` is applied (`<th>`)